# Importing mysql gives many errors when running wasm-pack

Tags: mysql, rust, webassembly

I'm very new to rust and Web Assembly and have a simple sample site. So far, it's just been very simple stuff and it's all working fine. Next I want to see about connecting to MySQL.

To Cargo.toml, I added:

```
    [dependencies]
    wasm-bindgen = "0.2.50"
    mysql = "*"
```

Everything compiles fine without the mysql part. Once I add `mysql="*"`, I get many (317) errors.

Some error samples:

```
[INFO]: Checking for the Wasm target...
[INFO]: Compiling to Wasm...
   Compiling net2 v0.2.33
   Compiling libc v0.2.62
error[E0432]: unresolved import `sys`
  --> /home/rich/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/net2-0.2.33/src
/tcp.rs:18:5
   |
18 | use sys::c;
   |     ^^^ maybe a missing `extern crate sys;`?
```

and

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `timeout2ms` in this scope
    --> /home/rich/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/net2-0.2.33/src/ext.rs:1145:18
     |
1145 |             .map(timeout2ms)
     |                  ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `SOL_SOCKET` in this scope
    --> /home/rich/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/net2-0.2.33/src/ext.rs:1149:33
     |
1149 |         set_opt(self.as_sock(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO,
     |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `SO_SNDTIMEO` in this scope
    --> /home/rich/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/net2-0.2.33/src/ext.rs:1149:45
     |
1149 |         set_opt(self.as_sock(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO,
     |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

So far, I haven't added any code to actually connect to the database. I'm only trying to build the project. The **only** difference is adding the mysql dependency.

I'm using this site info on using MySQL: [mysql - Rust](https://docs.rs/mysql/15.1.0/mysql/)

Given I'm new to Rust, I'm not sure what other info might be needed to help.

Edit: I've been googling for many of these errors without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty big difference; by doing so, you're adding, from the highest layer to the lowest:

- Libraries to deal with mysql
- Libraries to deal with the various compression mechanisms MySQL can use
- Libraries to deal with TLS
- Libraries to deal with sockets (where your errors are coming from)

If the entire chain was known to work with `wasm`, this would be fine. The problem is, it's not; as you can tell from the [Cargo.toml](https://docs.rs/crate/mysql/16.1.0/source/Cargo.toml) file for that library, it "knows" windows, macOS or linux as targets. In your case, `wasm` is neither of those three, and so it tries `net2` for networking, which depends on `libc`, which requires all those symbols that are suddenly missing.

You're going to go down a very, very deep rabbit hole if you decide to push this forward. If you do, mention in the comments and I'll give you pointers. However, before you do, consider the following: if this is for a `wasm` worker, anybody with the code will be able to know the triplet (proto, host, port) to access the MySQL server you'll be using, along with the credentials. This may also open serious infrastructure issues as you will not necessarily know what is a trusted client, and what isn't.

(I'm not going to lie to you, it's also going to be a **lot** of work, and most of it will not be easy. For instance, I wouldn't go down that hole)

Comment: You might be right. Especially considering that this is just a "I feel like learning wasm" project. (This was never going to go into release.) The good news is that this is part of the learning experience!

Comment: FWIW there'd be another problem, you would need a bridge in between; this may have changed since but last time I had a proper look at webassembly the only methods of communication available were webRTC, websockets and HTTP(S). So, you'd have been SOL one step further.

Comment: As for learning, the real learning experience is the journey, not the destination :-)